# Gigabit Dual WAN Cisco or Juniper Router / Firewall?

Tags: vpn, firewall, cisco, gigabit

Hi I am currently looking for a Gigabit Dual WAN Cisco or Juniper Router / Firewall. Can someone please make a recommendation for me. I cannot find anything Thank you!

Comment: What are you tryign to accomplish?

Comment: We have a Cisco 506E PIX. We have to different ISP's running to our building, we want to have something that involves fail over. We just rewired our building with cat6 so just looking to find a router that supports our needs

Comment: anyone got any form of idea??

Answer (score 1):

What gear you get will depend on what kind of internet (speed and layer 1 connectivity) you have. As far as how to do a dual provider redundant system is a different matter. What you want to do is get 2 routers with the correct WICs for your internet. Then use [HSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol) or [VRRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRRP) to create a failover pair.

Also you should really consider upgrading you Pix to an ASA pair to provide the highest level of redundancy. The setup would look something like this

clients -> ASA A/A or A/S pair -> HSRP/VRRP router pair -> internet

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a Cisco 2811 with a pair of Fast Ethernet ports (or ADSL HWICs) depending on how your internet is delivered.

One of the technologies you might want to test out is [OER](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6628/products_ios_protocol_option_home.html).

If you want to do failover via BGP, this is a good router also.  You might want to bung a stack more RAM in the router if you need full BGP table support

Answer (score 0):

The [Juniper Netscreen Secure Services Gateway (SSG140)](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/local/pdf/datasheets/1000181-en.pdf) (warning, PDF) has two copper Gb interfaces and are capable of 300Mb/s through the firewall function.  There are a number of ways of doing either fail-over or aggregations strategies with these firewalls.

We have deployed quite a few Netscreen firewalls of various types, and for the most part have not any problems that were not of our own making.